# do i have to put AN in the sentence before incorrect diagnosis?

Tags: american-english

> Four of the eight participants reported that they had incorrect diagnosis of their condition at the early stage.

Comment: [diagnosis](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/diagnosis) _plural_ diagnoses

Comment: Thank you for asking. When a question asks for proofreading or rewriting (“how should I write this?”, “is this correct?”, “which is correct?”), that is out of scope for this site and may be removed. See: “[What topics can I ask about here? - Help Center](/help/on-topic)”. If there is an unstated specific concern, such as “What does (word) mean in context?” or “How does (grammar or punctuation rule) apply in context?” try asking that question instead. Also check out: “[Where can I ask for free proofreading? – Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7571)”.

Comment: Also see: “[How much research is needed? – EL&U Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5039#5043)”. Every Stack Exchange question should describe the asker's prior efforts to find an answer, and explain why the results were not adequate to answer the question. Some research is required on every question. This is called our research requirement. The link I gave above has more information about the research requirement.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds awkward because it is partway between two possible structures. You can use either the singular

> an incorrect diagnosis

as each person had one diagnosis, or the plural

> incorrect diagnoses

as between them they had multiple diagnoses.